# Simplifying Scala expression calculating ratio

Tags: scala, rectangles, aspect-ratio

I'm trying to calculate the aspect ratio of a `java.awt.Rectangle` in Scala. I'm going for the "**ratio of longer side to shorter side**" definition of aspect ratio, not the "width to height" type of aspect ratio.

The following code works, but is there any way to avoid temporary variable and turn it into a one-liner?

```
val sizes = Seq(rect.getWidth, rect.getHeight)
val aspectRatio = sizes.max / sizes.min
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An approach, assuming only two values are added to the sequence,

```
Seq(rect.getWidth, rect.getHeight).sorted.reverse.foldRight(1.0)( _ / _ )
```

The code you propose is more readable though, and lesser prone to errors, at most division by zero would need some care.

Comment: Creating sequence and doing 3 operations at it is too complicated solution to such easy task.

Answer (score 20):

You don't have to create sequence to compute min and max values. You can use Math methods instead

```
Math.max(rect.getWidth, rect.getHeight) / Math.min(rect.getWidth, rect.getHeight)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
val aspectRatio = if(rect.getWidth >= rect.getHeight) rect.getWidth / rect.getHeight else rect.getHeight / rect.getWidth
```

Comment: It is properly formatted. Please look at the last paragraph of the style guide: http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/control-structures.html, "Trivial conditions".
Besides, this is a really trivial task. I see no reason why we should use anything more than if/else here.